# Call to undefined method mysqli_result::numRows

Tags: php, mysqli

How can I get this to work?

```
class Database {
    
    public $mysqli;
    
    public function connect() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'hltv');
    }
    
    public function sqlQuery() {
        if($rows = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users")) {
            echo $rows->numRows();
        }
    }
    
                
}
```

says,

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::numRows() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hltv_new\includes\database\config.php on line 18

Comment: I highly recommend using PHP's PDO instead of writing your own naive wrapper around mysqli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method numRows, so you can't call it.

```
echo $rows->num_rows;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score -1):

`num_rows` is a property of `MySQLi_Result`, not a method (*ed: there is also no method named `numRows`*).

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

**Edit**

It's best not to rely on the `num_rows` property as its value varies depending on whether you use buffered or unbuffered result sets (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Your best bet is to issue a `SELECT COUNT(1) ...` query using the same clauses and joins to determine the correct row count.

Comment: There's a num_rows property, not a numRows property. Don't recommend issuing extra queries to get the size of a result set...

Comment: @Dan Why wouldn't you issue an extra query? It's the only reliable way to determine a result set size. If using PDO, it even specifically says this in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: Perhaps you missed the part where we know he's using MySQL (and isn't using PDO), and don't need a method that will be reliable across all RDBMS's that PDO can wrap, only one that will be reliable for MySQL. Issuing extra queries is deadly to real world apps. MySQL does return the row count for SELECT queries, unlike some other RDBMS's, and if you also want to count the size of the possible result set (excluding your LIMIT clause) you just add the SQL_COUNT_ROWS hint to the query. There are some caveats with that, but it's still better than telling someone to run extra queries.

Comment: @Dan There's nothing wrong with issuing a count query before the real thing. There's no other way to do things like pagination with other DB vendors so saying it's "deadly" is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. One query returns the result set (observing your `LIMIT`) and the count of rows matching the query for pagination. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: @Dan My point was that it's hardly "deadly" to issue such a query. There's plenty of other projects out there that aren't using MySQL and manage to survive. I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree on this one. I've been using Oracle for too long, jealous of these MySQL developers and their `LIMIT` queries :(